# sending file to client for download

Tags: javascript, file, reactjs, express, download

Hello I am trying to send a file from my express server to my front end to allow the user to download it when they click a button. I've created a route on the backend the sends over the byte array but I dont have the slightest idea of how to allow the user to download it.

what I'm trying to do here is allow one user to upload a file directly to my server then another user comes and downloads the file that was uploaded on a previous date.

i've gotten the upload part to work fine. now I'm just missing direction for the download part.

here is my express route being hit.

```
const path = require('path');

const getFile = (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../', req.query.file);
  console.log(filePath);
  res.download(filePath);
};
```

here is my onClick for my frontEnd function

```
download(file) {
    axios.get('/api/download/getFile', {
      params: {
        file,
      },
    })
    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      window.open(data.data);
    })
  }
```

and this is the error i keep on getting when i click the button

> Unable to open a window with invalid URL

make sense to me because I'm not getting a url I'm getting a byte array

Comment: How about `window.open('/api/download/getFile?file=yourfile');` ?

Comment: @RehbanKhatri ha i've spent 3 days on this and that works Thank you very much

Comment: Great! would like to mark this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
window.open('/api/download/getFile?file=yourfile');
```